My Poor Wounded Willow
My neighbor cut the branches of my willow tree that extended over his property to the sky. The branches are cut mid way, not to the base of the tree. Will these branches survive and continue to grow. The side of the tree facing my property was not touched, his side was hacked by a tree service no less. There is a lot I could say about this but I am trying to keep this conversation only about my tree and not the neighbor.

Hello, and welcome to the site.  I am sorry about your willow tree.  Could you please post a picture for us?  That would help a lot.

What part of the world are you in?

Most likely they will survive and sprout a bunch of new sub-branches near the cut ends.
